# Writing large binary file part by part

Tags: c, file-io

I am trying to do a fairly easy task but am stumped by how the FILE* works. So I am writing a binary file (las file) which has a header and then the points in binary format. Since this is a huge file, I am doing it part by part. But the problem comes when the file pointer writes almost 3/4th of the file correctly and then gives entirely wrong file position pointer.

```
//struct points written to 
struct las_points{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
    float time;
};
int writepoints(){
     outfilename = "pointcloud_13.las";
     fout = fopen(outfilename,"wb+");
     // numPts - total number of points to be processed
     // numRec - number of records processed every time
     numRec = numPts/4;
     las_points *lp;
     // ending size of the file
     int endSize = 0,j=0;
     // header is written 
     // endSize = 233
     for(i=0;i<numPts;i+=numRec){
        lp = (las_points*)malloc(sizeof(las_points)*numRec);
        // some processing done 
        printf("Iteration - %d\n",j);
        lasWritePoints(lp,fout,numRec,endSize);
        fflush(fout);
        free(lp);
        lp = NULL;
     }
     fclose(fout);
}
int lasWritePoints(las_points*lp, FILE* fout,int numRec,int &endSize){
     if(!fout || !lp){
          printf("File couldnt be written \n");
          exit(1);
     }
     printf("endSize - %d \n",endSize);
     fseek(fout,endSize,SEEK_SET);
     for(int i=0;i<numRec;i++) {
         fwrite(&lp[i].x,sizeof(float),1,fout);
         fwrite(&lp[i].y,sizeof(float),1,fout);
         fwrite(&lp[i].z,sizeof(float),1,fout);
         fseek(fout,8,SEEK_CUR);
         fwrite(&lp[i].time,sizeof(float),1,fout);
     }
     endSize = ftell(fout);
     printf("endSize - %d \n",endSize);
}
```

Only the writing of the binary file is reproduced. The problem is that for the first four iterations for a file, it runs smoothly. Then at the end of last iteration, the endSize it gives is lesser than the beginning endSize.

```
 Output:
 Total size of file to be read: 1258456752
 Iteration : 0
 endSize : 233
 endSize : 550575041
 Iteration : 1
 endSize : 550575041
 endSize : 1101149849
 Iteration : 2
 endSize : 1101149849
 endSize : 1651724657
 Iteration : 3
 endSize : 1651724657
 endSize : 54815783
```

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is your endSize supposed to be larger than the `size of file to be read` ?

Comment: Yeah it is supposed to be bigger.

Comment: Then what should the `endSize1` be?  It could be larger than your int as a poster commented already.  You can even use `unsigned int`.

Comment: I tried to change the int to long and unsigned int. Its still giving me the same numbers. Is it something about the File that I am missing?

Comment: You know that after every `fwrite` call, the file pointer is advanced by 1 right?  Just wondering b/c you make 3 `fwrite` calls then you `fseek(fout,8,SEEK_CUR);` (which advances another 8 bytes). Then make one more `fwrite` call.  In total you advance the pointer `(4 X sizeof(float)) + 8` (24) bytes per a loop.   I think the problem may be that you aren't managing the file pointer correctly.  Your type size should be fine as an `int` type should do the trick, though I would always use an `unsigned int` in these situations.

Comment: So one iteration writes 24 bytes right? That is exactly how the file structure is set up. According to what I read in C++ reference, "The position indicator of the stream is advanced by the total number of bytes written".

Comment: I wrote up an answer below.  Can't believe I didn't see it earlier.

Comment: `lp = (las_points*)malloc(sizeof(las_points)*numRec);` is a syntax error in C (a struct definition is **not** a typedef). Are you using a C++ compiler ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to dereference `endSize`.

You are assigning the file size/position to a pointer resulting in your unexpected behavior.

```
endSize = ftell(fout);
```

s/b

```
*endSize = ftell(fout);
```

This is one of the most common mistakes in C.

Answer (score 1):

You are writing more bytes than can be represented by a 32-bit `int` (about 2 billion = 2 GB). Use a `long` to store the results of `ftell()`:

```
long endSize = ftell(fout);
printf("endSize - %ld\n", endSize);
```

Comment: I changed the int to long and am still getting the same numbers.

Comment: Did you change *all* instances of the `int` type for that variable?

Comment: Yes, I checked that part. Trying to print File pointer at every iteration now.

Comment: I printed the size after every loop in the last stage. IT seems that it is writing till the range of int (2,147,483,648) and then getting to a much smaller size (~11,000,000). This behaviour seems very weird to me.

Comment: That sounds like *something* is still overflowing. I'm not sure what would be, though.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting stuck with the 32-bit versions of file access functions. What platform/compiler/file system are you using?

If you are on:

- Linux using gcc try adding -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 to your compiler command
- Windows using [mingw](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libgw32c.htm) try using fseeko and ftello
- a 32-bit Windows with Visual C++ try using [_open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0kc8e3z.aspx) (not quite a drop-in replacement)
- a file system that has a 2GB file size limit then my condolences

Comment: Iam using Visual C++. I will try using _open

Comment: I tried using _open. Its still writing till the specified limit and then giving the size as -ve of the limit and continuing to wind down. So I guess its the last option.